# .class:nth-child(even) not working?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have an issue with `nth-child`, any Idea whats wrong?

HTML:

```
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="by">Euismod nam.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
...
        </div>
        <div class="date">12-15-23</div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="by">Euismod nam.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
...
        </div>
        <div class="date">12-15-23</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/*--*/
.comment {
    width:600px;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:0;
    margin-top:5px;
    padding:0;
    border:solid 1px #CCC;  
    /*border-top:none;*/
}
.comment .header {
    margin:0;
    padding:1px 2px;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#B2A98A;
    color:#FFF;
}
.comment .header:nth-child(even) {
    background:#62798B;
}
.comment .header .by {
    float:right;
    z-index:90;
}
.comment .content {
    margin:0;
    padding:5px 2px;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#FeFeFe;
    color:#000;
}
.comment .date {
    margin:0;
    padding:1px 2px;
    overflow:auto;
    background:rgba(178,169,138,0.5);
    color:#FFF;
}
.comment .date:nth-child(even) {
    background:rgba(98,121,139,0.5);
}
```

I don't see an issue within the code, or am I missing something? [[JSFIDDLE]](http://jsfiddle.net/Qn49d/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.header` is only one child in `.comment`, you should select parent :

```
.comment:nth-child(even) .header {
    background:#62798B;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qn49d/1/

Comment: You beat me to it. Same with `.date`.  And because `.date` and `.header` divs are direct desendents it would be more efficient to use `.comment:nth-child(even) > .header`

Answer (score 1):

Change from:

```
.comment .header:nth-child(even) {
```

to:

```
.comment:nth-child(even) .header {
```

The reason for this is that the `.comment` divs are siblings. If the `.header` elements were under a single `.comment` your initial markup would work.